# How to derive the $t$-$J$ model from the Hubbard model in the $U \gg t$ limit

Tags: condensed-matter, operators

Assa Auerbach derives the $t$-$J$ model starting with the zeroth-order Hamiltonian $\mathscr{U} = U \sum n_{i\uparrow} n_{i\downarrow}$ and then includes the hopping term $\mathscr{T}=-\sum t_{ij} c_{i\sigma}^* c_{i\sigma}$ as a perturbation. Eventually he arrives at an effective Hamiltonian on the singly occupied subspace of the Fock space, i.e.,
$$
H^\text{eff} = P_s \mathscr{T} P_s + P_s \mathscr{T} [P_d (E-(\mathscr{U} +\mathscr{T})] P_d]^{-1} \mathscr{T} P_s
$$
where $P_s,P_d$ are the projection operators onto the singly and doubly occupied subspaces and
$$
P_s (E-H)^{-1}P_s = [E - H^\text{eff} (E)]^{-1}, \qquad H = \mathscr{T} +\mathscr{U}
$$

I can follow his argument up to this point, but I'm confused about the details of his next step, i.e., 
$$
H^\text{eff} = H^{t,J}(1+O(E/U) +O(t/U))
$$
where
$$
H^{t,J} = P_s \left[\mathscr{T} - \frac{1}{U} \sum t_{ij} t_{jk} c_{is}^* c_{js} n_{j\uparrow} n_{j\downarrow} c_{js'}^* c_{ks'} \right]P_s
$$

Can anyone elaborate the details and show this the statement is true in an operator sense?